# VB Script GetObject method error...Help please WMI

Tags: vbscript, wmi

at this point i get error message:

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
          & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
          & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

---

```
Error: Invalid procedure call or Argument: "GetObject"
Code: 800A005
Source: Microsoft VBScript Runtime error
```

Comment: The recent edit removed an important problem, which makes it difficult to offer sensible corrections. :(

Comment: @Spida; can you post all the code; this snippet works for me. Also, what OS are you running this on?

Comment: What Spida posted is missing a \ he needs to confirm if that is in the code or was just a typo here.

Comment: Ok, so based on the comment below I put the \ back in but left the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Complete rewrite.

Here is the code generated by [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en), with very minor editing.

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    MsgBox "CurrentTimeZone: " & objItem.CurrentTimeZone
Next
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but can you please point out where have i forgot to put back slash as i just compared the code with your's and they are exactly same

Comment: The post was edited and the original problem no longer visible. I have quoted the original post in my reply. You can view the original post by clicking "edited n minutes go".

Comment: Hi Remou thanks for the update, but am pasting my whole code, can you please make the changes as i am struglling, i have done as what you said but it still gives me error:
**********************************

Comment: sComputer="."
Set oWMIService=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colComputer=oWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

Comment: Remou, the original post did have impersonate}!\\, but I think the SO formatter uses \ as an escape char outside of code, so \\ becomes \ (see how it did this in your edit as well).

Comment: I will note that in future :)